# React addEventListener duplicate listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, keydown

I am making a gallery app in React and I stucked 'cuz when I want to change img by key (left & right arrow) React/browser/JS? duplicates listener, as you can see:

[image: console.log screen]

The code looks like this:

```
const handleKey = (e) => {
        console.log(`user has pressed ${e.key}`);
        if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
            previousPicture();
        }
        if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
            nextPicture();
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKey);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKey);
    });
```

I tried to:

- paste handleKey inside useEffect;
- use empty dependencies array;
- paste into dep array activeIndex;
- make it in this way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners

When I tried e.g. this, app worked fine, but it was necessary to press TAB & then using arrows.

```
<Wrapper isOpen={isOpen} tabIndex={0} onKeyDown={handleKey}>
// content...
</Wrapper>
```

When I am navigating/changing images by buttons everything works well.

EDIT:
I modified code and added useCallback (thanks kind user). The 'duplicate issue' is gone, but I can't navigate with arrows. I tried to use in nextPic/prevPic callbacks: [activeIndex], [], and no dep array and still doesn't work.

I've created sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/dry-frog-tn86k2

Comment: Hello, do you have some minimal example for your issue? Like codesandbox?

Comment: Define `handleKey` inside the function you use for `useEffect`. Otherwise, every time the component is rendered, a new `handleKey` will be created and `window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKey)` will have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use empty dependencies array;

Leaving the *dependency array* empty will have no expected effect, since you need to have the reference to the *handler* function.

You'd have to wrap the `handleKey` function with `useCallback` hook to persist the reference between renders, so the *cleanup* that takes place in `useEffect` points to the right `handleKey` function instance.

**Note**: You'd probably have to wrap the `previousPicture` and `nextPicture` with `useCallback` as well. Depends how it is initialized.

```
const handleKey = useCallback((e) => {
    console.log(`user has pressed ${e.key}`);
    if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
        previousPicture();
    }
    if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
        nextPicture();
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKey);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKey);
}, [handleKey]);
```

Comment: I attached sandbox to my question.

Comment: @lukaasz555 It works perfect. You only forgot about dependencies for `handleKey` function. `[previousPicture, nextPicture]`

Comment: Hahaha, you're right! Thank you so much for help!:)